# How to display field if entry exists in join table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I'm writing a query that display data from our `issues` table. We have another table called `labels` and a join table called `issues_labels`. We usually assign an issue a label of 'High-Priority', 'Medium-Priority' or 'Low-Priority.

I'm unsure how to write my query so it would return this result:

```
Id         | Title                  | Priority
2            everything is broken     Low-Priority
4            internets is down        High-Priority
```

I write queries all the time, but the simplicity (or not) of this one is driving me nuts. Do I need to write 3 sub-queries to pull issues that are linked to each label as so:

```
with hp_issues as (
SELECT *
FROM issues
INNER JOIN issues_labels on issues_labels.issue_id = issue.id
WHERE issues_labels.label_id = 10 --id for high priority issue
)
....
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming issues_labels is a table that connects issues and labels in a many-to-many situation, you could do:

```
select
  i.id,
  i.title,
  l.priority
from issues i
left join issues_labels il on il.issues_id = i.id
left join labels l on l.id = il.labels_id
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b78ee/1

For any reason if one of your issues has more than one priority and you wanted it to be published as

`5  |  Some title  |  High Priority, Low Priority`

you can do:

```
select
  i.id,
  i.title,
  string_agg(l.priority, ',')
from issues i
left join issues_labels il on il.issues_id = i.id
left join labels l on l.id = il.labels_id
group by
  i.id,
  i.title
```

This is similar to MySQL's `group_concat()`

Example for that is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3dce4/2

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Didn't know about the `string_agg` function, super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Can an issue only have one label? If so, I think the many-to-many is not needed.

However, you should be able to do something like:

```
SELECT i.issueID, i.title, l.priority
FROM issue AS i
    LEFT JOIN issue_label as il on i.issueID = il.issueID
    LEFT JOIN label as l on l.labelID = il.labelID
WHERE issue_label = 10;
```